# javascript anonymous autoexec with parameter

Tags: javascript

i am creating a javascript object with anonymous function like this

```
(function(){
  window['d'] = this;
  this.sayHello = function(){
    console.log("hello world");
  } 
})();
```

how do i pass parameter to the `d` object so that i can call it like `d(SOMEPARAMS).sayHello()` also can be call with `d.sayHello()`. what need to be change and where?

Comment: What do you think `d` is? `d` is just an Object.

Comment: so, how do i make a jquery like function? `$().something()` or `$.something()` ?

Comment: `$` is actually a function object and `something` is just an attribute of that function object.

Comment: @thefourtheye i know about that object, what i am trying to understand is that what you call `function object` ?

Comment: In JavaScript, except the primitives and literals, everything is an Object. So, they can have attributes of their own. The same way, functions can also have their own attributes.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(){
  var pars = arguments[0] || {};
  window['d'] = this;
  this.sayHello = function(){
    console.log("hello world");
  } 
})({a:'test'})
```